# Select with inner join only returns one result

Tags: mysql

I have problems selecting username from one table with PK and sum of column  from another table with FK.

```
SELECT p.username, sum(t.amount)
FROM pdo p
INNER JOIN transactions t
    ON  t.affiliateid = p.affiliateid
```

This only returns one username with the the amount for that username summed up (as it should). No other entries are returned. "affiliateid" is the primary key in table pdo and the foreign key in table transactions.

I`m new to sql and have no clue as to why this happens, if I run this query from "pdo" and another table "userdata" everything works.

```
SELECT p.username, u.avatar
FROM pdo p
INNER JOIN userdata u
     ON  u.affiliateid_fk = p.affiliateid
```

Is it because the FK column is named differently from the PK column?

Comment: You must `group by p.username`

Comment: This is indeed the solution, however now it only displays the entries that have data in transactions. How can I make it display every username despite some not having any data in transactions?

Comment: Change to left join.